# python generator creating list of items fed from another genertator

Tags: python, list, generator

I am trying to create a list of batches from an input generator function, but it doesn't yield the list I am expecting.

```
def batch_generator(items, batch_size):
new = []
i = 0

for item in items: 
    new.append(item)
    i += 1
    print('new: ', new, i)
    if i == batch_size:
        print('i = batch')
        i = 0
        yield new
        new = []


def _test_items_generator():
    for i in range(10):
        yield i

print(list(map(lambda x: len(x), 
               batch_generator(_test_items_generator(), 3))))
```

I am trying to get the output to be [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4 ,5], [6, 7, 8], [9]]
The yield appears to be sending the batch_size instead of the information in the new list.  Trying to get my head to understand how these generators work!

Comment: Can you please fix the indentation of your code?

Comment: As far as I can tell, you just need to add `if new: yield new` at the bottom of the `batch_generator` function.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem lies in your last line:

```
print(list(map(lambda x: len(x), 
           batch_generator(_test_items_generator(), 3))))
```

`batch_generator` yields `new` which contains a list. Your `map(lambda x: len(x)` then returns the len of each list. You then print the list of lengths returned by `map()`.

Here is the code that produces the output you expect:

```
def batch_generator(items, batch_size):
    new = []
    i = 0

    for item in items: 
        new.append(item)
        i += 1
        print('new: ', new, i)
        if i == batch_size:
            print('i = batch')
            i = 0
            yield new
            new = []

    yield new # yield the last list even if it is smaller than batch size

def _test_items_generator():
    for i in range(10):
        yield i

print(list( batch_generator(_test_items_generator(), 3)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You generator is working correctly. But in your test, you map the result lists to their size `lambda x: len(x)`

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to the `batch_generator` function:

```py
def batch_generator(items, batch_size):
    current_batch = []

    for i, item in enumerate(items):
      current_batch.append(item)

      if len(current_batch) == batch_size:
        yield current_batch
        current_batch = []

    if len(current_batch) < batch_size:
      yield current_batch
```